# Как написать запрос с выводом значений таблиц в периоде по месяцам, а также чтобы показывалась дата , но пустые были поля?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Столкнулся с такой задачей. Мне нужно вывести с таблицы данные о списаниях. Но проблема в том, что требуется это сделать, чтобы каждый месяц из периода, например: от "2000-01-01" до "2010-01-01" показывал, что в месяце было списание, а если нет, то показывает только месяц с Null полями. Через такой запрос я смог найти только, что существует в таблице.

```
select *from journal where data between '2000-01-01' and '2010-01-01';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: структура таблицы]

Все значения в таблице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо генерировать опорную таблицу-календарь, и связывать с ним внешне рабочую таблицу.

Comment: @Akina у вас нет случайно примера создания такой таблицы?

Comment: [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) либо [generate_series() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html). Второе проще.

Comment: @Akina благодарю